# How to group li into ul then move into a parent li?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Let's say I have a list coded like this:

```
    <ul id="Folder" name="Folder">
    <li value="0">Top Folder</li>
    <li value="11">2nd Folder 01</li>
    <li value="17" class="third">---3rd Folder 01-01</li>
    <li value="18" class="third">---3rd Folder 01-02</li>
    <li value="383" class="fouth">------4th Folder 01-02-01</li>
    <li value="384" class="fifth">---------5th Folder 01-02-01-01</li>
    <li value="385" class="fifth">---------5th Folder 01-02-01-02</li>
    <li value="386" class="fifth">---------5th Folder 01-02-01-03</li>
    <li value="387" class="fifth">---------5th Folder 01-02-01-04</li>
    <li value="388" class="fifth">---------5th Folder 01-02-01-05</li>
    <li value="19" class="third">---3rd Folder 03</li>
    <li value="20" class="third">---3rd Folder 04</li>
    <li value="22" class="third">---3rd Folder 05</li>
    <li value="130" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-01</li>
    <li value="131" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-02</li>
    <li value="132" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-03</li>
    <li value="133" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-04</li>
    <li value="134" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-05</li>
    <li value="398" class="fouth">------5th Folder 01-02-05-06</li>
    <li value="158">2nd Folder 02</li>
    <li value="257" class="third">---3rd Folder 02-01</li>
    <li value="258" class="third">---3rd Folder 02-02</li>
    <li value="259" class="third">---3rd Folder 02-03</li>
    <li value="16">2nd Folder 03</li>
    <li value="382" class="third">---3rd Folder 03-01</li>
    <li value="51" class="third">---3rd Folder 03-02</li>
    <li value="113" class="fouth">------4th Folder 03-02-01</li>
    <li value="125" class="fouth">------4th Folder 03-02-02</li>
    </ul>
```

And I used jquery:

```
    $('li.fifth').wrapAll('<ul>');
    $('li.fouth').wrapAll('<ul>');
    $('li.third').wrapAll('<ul>');
```

So I can group all the 5th, 4th and 3rd li into a group.

The problem I'm having now is, how I can move the 5th ul group into the 4th li parent? and the 4th ul group into 3rd li etc...

Comment: You can't nest `ul` elements like that. Where are you getting this HTML?

Comment: following on from Blenders accurate comment, what are you trying to achieve - are you hoping to make a nested list to show some kind or hierarchy ?

Comment: Hi all,

What I trying to do is nest lots li into different ul.

This is the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124387/jquery-group-li-into-ul-based-on-dash

I got a dropdown and I want to make them into multiple nest lists.

Comment: I left an answer to your original question. You can probably avoid all this wrapping business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see a way to use `.wrapAll`.

Instead, I made use of the `prev + next` selector.

The code below gets the first `<li class="fifth">` that is right after an `<li class="fouth">`. It then backs up to the previous element, which is the `<li class="fouth">`. Then it creates a `<ul>` and starts moving the `<li class="fifth">` elements into it. Last, it puts the `<ul>` at the end of the `<li class="fouth">`.

Note: The `<ul>` is built outside of the DOM and then inserted into the DOM. That way, the DOM is never in an invalid state, where a `<ul>` is a sibling of an `<li>` or something like that.

I put the code in a function that can be called over and over.

```
function moveToParent(parentClass, childClass) {
    $('li.' + parentClass + ' + li.' + childClass).each(function(e) {
        var $parentFolder = $(this).prev();
        var $ul = $('<ul/>');
        while ($parentFolder.next().is('li.' + childClass)) {
            $parentFolder.next().appendTo($ul);
        }
        $parentFolder.append($ul);
    });
}

moveToParent('fouth', 'fifth');
moveToParent('third', 'fouth');
```

[Live Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJM3V/1/)

Note: I left "fourth" misspelled as "fouth" since that is what you have in your html.

Comment: Legend! prev and next solved them all, .warpAll can't do what I after.

* yes thanks for the correction!